# IE 8 on different machines not rendering the same color

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, background-color

Considering two different client machines:

- Both using Internet Explorer 8
- Both using Windows XP
- Both are 32-bit machines
- Both accessing the same Intranet site (that I have built)

Why, on one machine does the background-color render normally, as it should, while on the other machine, it doesn't render the right color in the main wrapperDiv (that is, it just adopts the color of the parent element, `<body>`).

The full CSS rule that I am using for the `<div id="wrapperDiv">` element is shown below:

```
#wrapperDiv
{
    background-color: rgba(0, 148, 255, 0.50);
    width: 900px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
    -ms-border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
    border-color: #000;
    border-style: outset;
    border-width: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}
```

As you can see, I am using [PIE](http://css3pie.com/), however, I don't think that has anything to do with this issue.

I would understand the differences if they were using different browsers (or different versions of the same browser), different OSs (or different versions of the same OS), etc., but why, when the browsers and OSs are the same, does the color not render on one of the machines? (e.g., it simply takes the parent background color). Is this a common issue, or do I have some kind of rare crazy circumstance here?

Thanks!

Comment: IF the software is identical, AND the settings are identical then you should get identical results. Is one computer using a shitty monitor? (Purposely capitalized 'if' there)

Comment: If the CSS is loaded from file you may need to try to clear your browser cache first...

Comment: Does the machine with the color issue have any toolbars or Add-Ons installed?  On my website, the Yahoo Toolbar was causing issues with JavaScript.

Comment: I did some checking and one of the machines were holding a cache, however, they are both not rendering the color :(.  My issue must have something to do with a scenario in which PIE does not support this specific rgba setting for some reason... Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible according to me...only issue I can see here could be cache on the other system, kinda IE on the other system must be caching old CSS file, either press `ctrl+f5` for hard refresh or clear the temporary files and see if it works..

And I just read so for your information IE 8 doesn't support `rgba` so do it like this...

```
background-color: #/*RGBA Equivalent HEX*/;
background-color: rgba(0, 148, 255, 0.50);
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware that IE 8 and under does not support rgba, however, I am using PIE, which is supposed to handle that. Also, there is no rgba equivalent hex that will render with opacity. I can't simply use filter, either, because of the opacity inheritance issue, as I want one of the child elements to be fully opaque. RGBA seems to be the only practical way to do this, and PIE is supposed to handle that for browsers IE 8 and under.

Comment: Ya but it's just a fallback so that your div background doesnt go transparent

Comment: OIC, I should've payed more attention to your code. I suppose I'll have to do that, but I was hoping that PIE would be able to support all rgba settings, but, it is still a very innovative and useful project. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @VoidKing I got this idea when I was reading the book, I always mention fallbacks before latest properties so that it doesn't spoil the layout entirely :p

Comment: Also, it may be useful for everyone to know that (because of my code, shown above) I was supposed to include a line: '-pie-background: rgba(0, 148, 255, 0.50);' right after the other rgba line, to use this PIE feature as intended for machines IE9 and under. Just thought I would mention that since I didn't do that part right in the code shown above.